# Write a rotate_left(char *) function in C

Tags: c

How can we write a rotate_left(char*) function that takes a null-terminated string and rotate it to the left one character. For ex: "abcdef" --> "bcdefa"

So far i have:

```
 rotate_left(char* str){
  int i, lin;
   char buff[lin+1], temp;

   lin = strlen(str);
   strcpy(buff,str);




 }
```

Can anyone help me complete this function. Really appreciated.

Comment: For starters, you don't assign a value to `lin` before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I will use much of the question code.  Here is an alternate solution:

```
rotate_left(char* str){
   char ch;
```

1) Store the character that will to be rotated from the left side, to the right side.

```
   ch=*str;
```

2) Shift all characters in the string left one byte.

```
   memmove(str, str+1, strlen(str)-1);
```

3) Copy the rotated character to the end of 'str'.

```
   str[strlen(str)] = ch;
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
char last = str[0];
int len = strlen(str);

for(i=0; i< len-1; i++) { str[i] = str[i+1]; }
str[len-1] = last;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that rotation in place, like this:

```
char * rotate_left1 (char *str) {
    char ch;
    int i;

    ch = str[0];
    for (i = 0; str[i+1]; i++) {
        str[i] = str[i+1];
    }
    str[i] = ch;

    return str;
}
```